# GNU gprof showing calls in seconds instead of milliseconds

Tags: c++, gcc, profiling, gnu, gprof

Is there an option i am missing that i couldnt find? i have searched the internets and all the articles show the flat profile in milliseconds without any added option tags, but my gprof outputs the times in seconds.
I have built the code with the simple -pg option, and then used gprof without any options, so the default flat profile is generated.
EDIT: meant the `"self"` and `"total"` calls are in `s/call` and i want it in `ms/call`